# Can't convert a char to string using standard Linq methods?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to count the amounts of brackets in a given text using Linq standard methods. This is the code I have written so far.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Exercises
{
    class BracketExercise
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string bracketlist = "a(werawq4rqdcds()()()((((()DAs3";
            string value = "(";
            //string value2 = ")";
            
            bool result = bracketlist.Contains(value);
            Console.WriteLine($"Does string contain specified substring? {result}");
            if (result == true)
            {
                int freq = bracketlist.Count(f => (f == value));
                Console.WriteLine(freq);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Am I missing something? This piece gives me compiler error CS0019, Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'.
I tried changing "Value" to a var type, but that didn't work either.ch

Answer (score 3):

When using LINQ, a `string` is treated like it's an `IEnumerable<char>` This means that in the following code:

```
int freq = bracketlist.Count(f => (f == value));
```

`f` is of type `char`, not `string`. Since `value` is of type `string`, your code is trying to do `char == string`, which is the source of the error.

In this case, I would suggest you change your `value` to also be a `char`:

```
char value = '(';
```

Take note of the different `'` quotes. `"A"` is a `string`, `'A'` is a `char`. The quotes you use are important to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `int freq = bracketlist.Count(f => (f == value));` f is of type char (because the enumeration on a string works on char). You are comparing it to `value`, which is of type string. Change `string value = "(";` to `char value = '(';`. Note the single quotes used to declare a char (as opposed to using double quotes, which declares a string).

Answer (score 0):

Flater's answer addresses your main complaint, but I did want to discuss this some:

> I tried changing "Value" to a var type

There isn't a `var` *type*; var is you saying "compiler is allowed to decide the type". The compiler will then look at the type on the right hand side of the `=` and make a decision based on that

On the right hand side you have `"("` - this is a string; nothing makes it not a string so you'll end up in exactly the same place whether you write `string value` or `var value`

By now you know you could have written:

```
var v = '(';
```

That `v` would be a `char`, because `'('` is a char;

Other things would also result in chars:

```
var v = "("[0];
```

That's a string being indexed by an int, which is an operation that results in a char. In this case, the compiler would also infer a `char` type for `v`. That's not to say you'd do that - it's just to demo that `v` ends up as what the compiler determines the final outcoming type of the right hand operation is

---

Typically we aim to use `var` when it's obvious what the type is on the other side, or if it's something horrific, like the output of a LINQ query that includes other data and has a where clause etc, and we don't want type out `IIncludableQueryableSomethingThatsReallyLongAndDoesntMatter v = ...`

There are times when you should avoid using var if it makes the code harder to read:

```
//method name is poor; doesn't make it obvious what it does, or returns
//variable name is poor too; we'll have to rely on intellisense lots here
var v = DoProcess();
```

There are also times where you should avoid using var because it makes life hard work. Looping over old collections that don't implement `IEnumerable<T>` is a good example:

```
foreach(var row in someDataTable.Rows)
```

`row` here will end up typed as `object`, which is a nuisance to use. THis happens because `.Rows` is a DataRowCollection and the enumerator for it claims it returns an `object` - it's actually a DataRow but it's wrapped up inside an object. `foreach` will do a cast for you if you *don't* use `var`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in someDataTable.Rows)
```

And this is cleaner than `var`'ing it and having to cast:

```
foreach(var row in someDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
  ..

//or
foreach(var row in someDataTable.Rows){
  var actualRow = (DataRow)row;
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
string bracketlist = "a(werawq4rqdcds()()()((((()DAs3";
Char value = '('; // replace string char
bool result = bracketlist.Contains(value);
Console.WriteLine($"Does string contain specified substring? {result}");
if (result == true)
   {
      int freq = bracketlist.Count(f => (f == value));
      Console.WriteLine(freq);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the existence of the characters in the string by using Contains method. The count will give you valid result EVEN if there are no instances of the character you are searching. PF the simplest implementation.

```
string bracketlist = "a(werawq4rqdcds()()()((((()DAs3";
char charToFind = '(';
int bCount = bracketList.Count(x => x == charToFind);
```

Remember, string is a character array.